# How can I set scrolltop of DIV tag without using javascript?

Tags: html, css

```
<div id = "nav"></div>
```

I already know how to set scrollbar position of that DIV with Javascript(jQUery).
but what I want to know is how to set with HTML or CSS property something like

```
<div id = "nav" scrollTop = "100"></div>
```

or

```
<div id = "nav" style = "scrollTop:100px"></div>
```

is there any solution?

Comment: used padding-top .......

Comment: How can I use padding-top to set scrollbar position? I think it means only position of DIV not scrollbar in DIV.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot accomplish this to specifically go to exact position on the page without using javascript.

What you can however do is :

Create a div with the styles associated with it. The position where you want to goto.

```
<div id="top10px"></div>
```

and apply css as :

```
#top10px {position:absolute;top:10px;left:0}
```

And make these div's where ever you want to navigate to,

```
<div id="top0px"></div>    <div id="top100px"></div>      <div id="bottom0px"></div>
```

and apply styles accordingly.

Here's a fiddle : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3LvAZ/)